# Where to start reading GHC's source code

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to learn how various aspects of GHC, like type inference, pattern matching, and other code transformations, are implemented.

However the codebase is fairly large and the file names use a lot of acronyms (simpl, stg, stranal...). What do these mean, and how is the code organized?

Comment: @hammar, that looks good enough for an answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As hammar says, the [GHC commentary](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary) is probably the best place to start for learning about GHC itself. This does assume some prior knowledge of compilers in general, but if your primary interest is in modifying GHC you can probably get by with just a basic CS background.

If you're interested more generally in the principles behind GHC, e.g. if you want to learn how to write *your own* compiler, you'd probably be better served by [perusing Simon Peyton-Jones' myriad publications on relevant topics](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/papers.html), including [an entire book on implementing functional languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/index.htm) and [a "tutorial" book](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/) that goes through the implementation of a non-strict functional language.

Answer (score 8):

The [GHC commentary](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary) is a good place to start.